# Login plugin of TinyAuth for CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, plugins, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I have a problem with the login of the user, I have different tables for each user because they have different atributes (students, administrators, profesors) and I don't know how can I configure TinyAuth for more than one UserModel. Sorry for my poor english. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your life easier you should keep them all under the same `users` table, but have a `groups` table as well. The `groups` table will have `students`, `professors` and `administrators`. The `users` table will in turn have a `group_id` column where each user can have a reference to the `groups` table.

```
|users|
-> id
-> group_ip
-> username
-> first_name
-> last_name
-> created
-> updated

|groups|
-> id
-> name
-> created
-> updated
```

Using this technique requires you to have the right relations setup.

If you don't like to use `groups`, you can have a `role` field in your `users` table.

```
|users|
-> id
-> role
-> username
-> first_name
-> last_name
-> created
-> updated
```

Regardless of the choice you pick, you should not create multiple tables and expect uniform login to work nicely.

You should follow CakePHP's Blog tutorial to have a better understanding of how the `role` technique is used.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andre, the method you explain me sounds more easy to understand and of course will be helpful for my work.